# Fechas manejando datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, datepicker

Estoy haciendo un sistema de control de empleados, mi problema es con las fechas  ya que no me las guarda como debería 
    este codigo es el que utilizo para recabar los datos dentro de un formulario

```
<?php
//conectar a la base de datos 
include "conexion.php";
//realizar consulta 
$user_id=null;
$sql1= "select * from nomina where id= ".$_GET["id"];
$query = $con->query($sql1);
$person = null;
if($query->num_rows>0){
while ($r=$query->fetch_object()){
  $person=$r;
  break;
}

  }
?>

  <?php if($person!=null):?>

  <form role="form" method="post" action="php/actualizar.php"> //formulario para agregar o actualizar
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="folionomina">Folio Nomina</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->folionomina; ?>" name="folionomina" id="folionomina">
      <label for="nombre_emp">Nombre de Empleado</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->nombre_emp; ?>" name="nombre_emp" id="nombre_emp">
      <label for="sueldodiario">Sueldo Diario</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->sueldodiario; ?>" name="sueldodiario" id="sueldodiario">
      <label for="sueldosemana">Sueldo Semanal</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->sueldosemana; ?>" name="sueldosemana" id="sueldosemana">
      <label for="descinfonavit">Descuento Infonavit</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->descinfonavit; ?>" name="descinfonavit" id="descinfonavit">
      <label for="descfonacot">Descuento Fonacot</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->descfonacot; ?>" name="descfonacot" id="descfonacot">
      <label for="puesto_emp">Puesto Empleado</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->puesto_emp; ?>" name="puesto_emp" id="puesto_emp">
      <label for="fechalta">Fecha de Alta</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->fechalta; ?>" name="fechalta" id="fechalta">
      <label for="fechamodsal">Fecha de Modificacion de salario</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->fechamodsal; ?>" name="fechamodsal" id="fechamodsal">
      <label for="fechabaja">Fecha de Baja</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->fechabaja; ?>" name="fechabaja" id="fechabaja">
      <label for="sueldocontrato">Sueldo Contrato</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->sueldocontrato; ?>" name="sueldocontrato" id="sueldocontrato">
      <label for="fechaini">Fecha de Inicio</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->fechaini; ?>" name="fechaini" id="fechaini">
      <label for="totaldias">Total de Dias</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->totaldias; ?>" name="totaldias" id="totaldias">

      <label for="fechaini">Fecha de Inicio</label> //aqui es donde tengo la duda al mandar el dato de fecha no lo recibe correctamente
      <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->fechaini; ?>" name="fechaini" id="fechaini">



    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $person->id; ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Actualizar</button>
  </form>
  <?php else:?>
  <p class="alert alert-danger">404 No se encuentra</p>
  <?php endif;?>
```

Ahora mi duda viene con la siguiente parte que es la de guardar la fecha dentro de las tablas mi duda es la siguiente,  si coloco una función para convertir la fecha recibida en un arreglo y ese arreglo convertirlo a una nueva variable debe ir antes  o en que parte del siguiente código.

```
<?php
//aqui tengo duda de si poner una funcion que reciba la fecha y la cambie mediante un arreglo pero si seria antes o despues 




if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST["puesto"]) &&isset($_POST[$fechacambiada])){
        if($_POST["puesto"]!=""&& ){
            include "conexion.php";

            $sql = "insert into puestos(puesto,creadoel) value (\"$_POST[puesto]\",NOW())";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Agregado exitosamente.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";
            }else{
                print "<script>alert(\"No se pudo agregar.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";

            }
        }
    }
}



?>
```

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es que formatees la fecha en la propia query en `mysql`, suponiendo que el campo `fechaini` tiene un formato de fecha adecuado:

```
SELECT *, 
    DATE_FORMAT(fechaini, '%d/%m/%Y') AS fechaini_format FROM NOMINA WHERE id= ".$_GET["id"];
```

La otra opción es en php modificar el formato antes de rellenar el input correspondiente:

```
<?php 
$fechaini_format = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($person->fechaini));
?>
```

Comment: Carmen, entonces si no mal entendi en la query, reviso la fecha salga en un formato correcto y dos en el segundo codigo lo aplico antes de mandarlo, entonces en mi codigo de insercion ya no modificaria nada mas que realizar la operacion

Comment: Si lo haces en la query ya no necesitas hacerlo en php, deberías traer directamente el formato adecuado en $person->fechaini_format, como si fuera un campo más de tu tabla.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya con eso  puedo guardar directo

Comment: un placer frank ;)